# Unable to render file links (FileColumn) in Django-Tables2

Tags: python, django, file

I'm using Django-Tables2 to render a table which columns are: `ID`and `File`.

My table is defined in `tables.py`:

```
class FileTable(tables.Table):
    id = tables.Column(verbose_name="ID")
    f = tables.FileColumn(verose_name="File")
```

And here's what I'm sending to `FileTable`:

```
q1 ={
     id = model.id,  # String, type(model.id) == 'str'
     file = model.file  #FieldFile, type(model.file) == <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>
     }

     table = FileTable([q1])
     RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 25}).configure(table)

     ....
```

The problem is that Django keeps rendering my Filecomlum as '-':

```
|       ID         |File|
|------------------|----|
|DKWPRODSORWPDSKROT|  - |
|------------------|----|
|VLPQIENDJASO940D1O|  - |
```

I tried to follow the
[django-tables2 documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#django_tables2.columns.FileColumn)
but it doesn't have any working examples and I can't figure what's wrong.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what my problem was!
When creating the class `FileTable`, I defined the file attribute as
`f` but on my `q1` dictionary (which I'm using to call the table class)
the file attribute is called `field`. Therefore the key `f` appears as null.

So, when creating table classes for django-tables2, make sure that 
dict attributes are called exactly as the class attributes.